# <li> width and text-size-adjust

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble with the width of the li elements and the size of my text.
I'm using text-size-adjust to make text readable on mobile, the li height grows with the text but not the width, it stays at the text original size. So the texts overlap.

```css
* { text-size-adjust: 200%; }

#navigation{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}

#navigation ul{
    display: flex;
}

#navigation a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#navigation a:visited{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>BASE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/backgradient.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/navigation.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Projets</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Réseaux</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a>変態 白雪</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that is fully supported, text-size-adjust.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust ?  You must have more CSS and markup than that also, or a link to look closer.

Comment: I'm just using 
```css 
text-size-adjust: 300%
```  (and the prefixed) plus the css in the post.

Comment: Your provided code does not contain `text-size-adjust`

Answer (score 0):

since you have an issue with the text not being adjusted with the screensize, first you have to remove the font size defined within the class, then add the font size to `* {}` class by defining the size with **vw** (viewport width). That way the text size will follow the size of the browser window. Try the following example and see. For more information please check w3 documentation. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp

```css
* {
  font-size-adjust: 200%;
  font-size:4.5vw;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}

#navigation ul {
  display: flex;
}

#navigation a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

#navigation a:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
        <title>BASE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/backgradient.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/navigation.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Projets</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Réseaux</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a>変態 白雪</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```